# Dropdownlist databound to sqldatasource - inserted record doesn't show until page refreshed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist of suppliers which is bound to an sqldatasource.  A supplier can be added via a formview but once the insert button is clicked the record is inserted into the database but doesn't show on the dropdownlist.

The code for the sqldatasource is as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="sqlAddSupplier" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cctConnectionString%>" 
 ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cctConnectionString.ProviderName%>" 
 InsertCommand="suppliers_Insert" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="siteId" DefaultValue="0" Name="p_siteId" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="code" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The code for the dropdownlist and formview to add a supplier is as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="lstSuppliers" runat="server" CssClass="dropDownList" 
 AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="sqlSuppliers" DataTextField="name" 
 DataValueField="id" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("supplierId") %>' >
    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAddSupplier" CssClass="groupBoxPageWidth">

    <asp:FormView ID="fvAddSupplier" runat="server" DataSourceID="sqlAddSupplier" 
     OnItemInserted="fvAddSupplier_ItemInserted">

        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <b>Code:*</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCode" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("code") %>' CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            <b>Name *:</b>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>' CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdInsertSupplier" Text="Save" CssClass="buttonControlGreen" CommandName="Insert" OnClientClick="needToConfirm=false;" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="cmdCancelSupplier" Text="Cancel" CssClass="buttonControl" CommandName="Cancel" OnClientClick="needToConfirm=false;" />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
</asp:Panel>
```

The code behind for the ItemInserted event is as follows:

```
protected void fvAddSupplier_ItemInserted(object sender, FormViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    fvAddSupplier_CommandCompletion(e.Exception, e.KeepInInsertMode, "Inserted");
}

protected void fvAddSupplier_CommandCompletion(Exception sqlException, bool keepInMode, String procedureExecuted)
{
    Panel pnlAddSupplier = (Panel)fvProduct.FindControl("pnlAddSupplier");
    Label lblAddSupplierError = (Label)pnlAddSupplier.FindControl("lblAddSupplierError");

    if (sqlException != null)
    {
        keepInMode = true;
    }
}
```

It will refresh the dropdownlist if I call Response.Redirect to refresh the whole page but I assume this should happen at PostBack anyway?  I have also tried calling DataBind on the dropdownlist once the record has been inserted but then see the following error:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

I am relatively new to asp.net so may be missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: refresh or rebind the datasource as you did initially

Comment: I try to refresh or rebind the datasource by calling lstAddSuppliers.DataBind() when the insert is complete but see the Databinding methods... error in my original post.  Is there any other way to refresh/rebind it?